# word problem - elementary number theory - divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that the product of three consecutive integers is divisible by 504 if the middle one is a cube

Comment: Can you show us your effort in order to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

We need $$a^3(a^6-1)$$  divisible by $504=7\cdot2^3\cdot3^2$

Now by Fermat's Little Theorem $7$ divides $a^7-a$ which divides $a^3(a^6-1)=a^2(a^7-a)$

Now if $2|a,$  $$2^3|a^3$$ hence $a^3(a^6-1)$

else $2\nmid a, (2,a)=1$ using [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html), $$2^3|(a^{2^{3-1}}-1)=a^2-1$$ for odd $a$

Check for $3^2$